# Object store exception in mule

Tags: java, mule

I am getting **`ObjectStoreException`** when I am using Request-Reply VM endpoint in my mule flow(using `Mule 3.4.0`). Why this exception is thrown by Mule and How to resolve it?

**Exception:**

```
Exception stack is:
1. null (org.mule.api.store.ObjectAlreadyExistsException)
  org.mule.util.store.PartitionedObjectStoreWrapper:52 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/store/ObjectAlreadyExistsException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.store.ObjectAlreadyExistsException
    at org.mule.util.store.PartitionedObjectStoreWrapper.store(PartitionedObjectStoreWrapper.java:52)
    at org.mule.util.store.MonitoredObjectStoreWrapper.store(MonitoredObjectStoreWrapper.java:101)
    at org.mule.routing.requestreply.AbstractAsyncRequestReplyRequester$InternalAsyncReplyMessageProcessor.process(AbstractAsyncRequestReplyRequester.java:323)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Note: I am getting the expected output that I want, but my mule flow is throwing the above mentioned exception.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you be experiencing: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7262 ? Since you haven't shown your flow, we can not tell...

Comment: Hey David, Thanks, the above mentioned link helped me to figure out the exact cause. My outbound endpoint is getting hit twice.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem came back on 3.9.0,

We had same problem in 3.9.0 with **Request-Reply processor**.
Adding below to outbound vm

```
<message-properties-transformer>
                <delete-message-property key="MULE_REPLYTO" />
            </message-properties-transformer>
```

solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18690979)

Comment: @ddarellis Trying to inform that this issue came back in 3.9.0 in a different processor. We can still solve the issue by adding the Given config in the Outbound end point for request reply.